# Magento 2 Which controller is used for Place Order

Tags: magento2, place-order

I find myself unable to place orders.

I wish to debug this.

Which controller is invoked/used when the place order button is clicked?
I would like to put a break point and start from there thanks.

Comment: M2 checkout uses web API instead of controllers. Thus, you need to debug apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a starting point in Quote.

> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::placeOrder

Answer (score 1):

First controller on place order is

`Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder.php` firstly it performs validation, if validation passed then It goes to

```
        $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();
```

Comment: Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder::execute is not called when Place Order is clicked. One can put a break point and see for himself.